# Current Node Icon not same as Default Node Icon

Tags: c#, treeview, icons

I have a Treeview with named nodes. To help the user, every Node can have one of four icons. The default Item (0) is white.

I got confused but know I have pinned down the "wrong behavior".

The icons get set up correctly and are correct in my Treeview, but every time I "click" on a node it gets selected and the default Icon is shown (white).

How can I change the behaviour to make the selected node show its correct icon?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First giv the Node Image a Name:

```
this.treeView.ImageList.Images.Add("TABLE", global::OrangeUI.Properties.Resources.table);
```

Than you can set the different Icons like that:

```
this.treeView.SelectedNode.ImageKey = "TABLE"; this.treeView.SelectedNode.SelectedImageKey
= "TABLE";
```